# VC++ OpenGl Framework

Tags: .net, opengl, visual-c++

I'm new in OpenGL.
I know C# has OpenGl Framework.And we can use it like this:

```
using CsGL.OpenGL;
```

Is there a framework for using OpenGL in VC++.net too ?

Best Regards...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are working in Managed C++, you can access the OpenGL API directly using something like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")

#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
```

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/OpenGLViewWinForms.aspx) from the code project gives an excellent overview.  It provides source code for including an OpenGL rendering context in a win forms application.